# How can I see what the show function is doing in a controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route that goes to: `GET    /api/:api_version/publishers/:id(.:format)                                                              {:controller=>"api/publishers", :action=>"show"}`

So I pop open the `publishers_controller` in `api` and it looks:

```
# Provides access to publisher information
class Api::PublishersController < Api::BaseResourceController
  inherit_resources
  respond_to_data_formats

  before_filter :find_publisher
  before_filter :require_publisher_login, :only => :authenticate

  actions :show

  # Note: We remove App scope from cache path, since Publisher info should be cached across all apps
  caches_action :show, :login, :cache_path => lambda {|c| {:version => c.send(:publisher_version), :model_version => Publisher.cache_config.version}}, :expires_in => 60.seconds

  # Action redirects the top frame to the publisher's site (for the user to log in)
  def login
    # Prevent infinite loop where the page redirects to itself.
    raise ArgumentError, 'Publisher website url is not configured' if @publisher.website_url.blank?
  end

  def authenticate 
    respond_with(@publisher)
  end

  private

    def find_publisher
      params[:publisher_id] = params[:id]
      super
    end

    def publisher_version
      @publisher.lock_version
    end

end
```

There is no `show` function, so how can I see what it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class inherits the `show` method, presumably from `Api::BaseResourceController`. And if I had to bet, I'd guess that `Api::BaseResourceController` uses [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) or something similar, which just assumes that the `show` method should do a very typical thing: find the record and display it using the available template.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to find that template.. any ideas of where to look?